# Morava E-theory of classifying spaces

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homotopy-theory

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group/finite group. Is Morava E-theory at height $n>1$ of $BG$ related to representation theory of $G$?

Comment: https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2000-13-03/S0894-0347-00-00332-5/S0894-0347-00-00332-5.pdf